# What plugin for wordpress to share comments on social networks automatically?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a wordpress plugin that add the comments to the social networks.
I mean, when an user write a comment on my blog, can it login with his social account and after it publish the comment, the plugin share it on his profile? (facebook, twitter?)

THanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do it mixed for different social networks. But you can try [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/) for Facebook. I've seen it in many websites (Wordpress and not Wordpress-powered)